# Neo4j Import Tool Hanging

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to import 22,148,908 nodes and 173,574,311 edges from csv files. I left the `neo4j-import` tool to run overnight, but the output hasn't changed since after 5 minutes of starting. The import seems to be hanging and the output is as follows:

```
[>:34.39 MB/s----|PROPERTIES(2)======|*NODE--------------------------------------|v:66.09 MB/s-] 16Mb
```

Looking at top says that the thread is still doing something. CPU util on that process is consistently above 50%. However, disk usage isn't growing and there are no lines in `messages.log`.

Are there debug options I can enable to figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I recall a recent issue where this might occur if the last character of the input file was a quote (`"`). If that's the case then just add a new-line and I think it should work.

Comment: Hi Mattias, here's a thread dump, since the data is sensitive: http://hastebin.com/qirajufube.avrasm.

If the number at the right of the progress bar is the number of nodes loaded, it seems  to get stuck at 17M every time so it might just be a line in that region. Loading the first million nodes works. Will poke around more tonight. There aren't quotes at the end, but I appended a newline to both files anyway. Didn't fix it though.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the thread dump. With it I can conclude that your import hanging is due to a race during shutdown. It's shutting down because there were some error during importing the nodes, an error we cannot see since it's hangning when shutting down. I'll fix this for 2.2 GA. I can post a github pull request so that you can follow when such is available.