# Neo4j bulk import doesn't work for big datasets

Tags: neo4j

I have used neo4j's bulk import before for a small/medium-sized prototype dataset and it worked like a charm. I am now using it to import the full dataset which consists of ~100 GB split into 7 csv files: 4 node csv files (each file with distinct label), and 3 edge csv files. The header is the first line of each file and I am using the following command (in Neo4j Desktop Terminal on Windows 10):

```
SET DATA=D:\Neo4jdb\data

.\bin\neo4j-admin import ^

--mode=csv ^

--database=full_kb.db ^

--ignore-duplicate-nodes true ^

--nodes %DATA%\nodes_assoc.csv ^

--nodes %DATA%\nodes_article.csv ^

--nodes %DATA%\nodes_term.csv ^

--nodes %DATA%\nodes_chunk.csv ^

--relationships %DATA%\edges_IN_ASSOC.csv ^

--relationships %DATA%\edges_IN_ARTICLE.csv ^

--relationships %DATA%\edges_IN_CHUNK.csv
```

The nodes import successfully after about 40 mins, but once the SORTING starts, this has maximized CPU usage (constant 100%), and has been going on for more than 24 hours (technically its not stuck because CPU is still being used at 100%. I can no longer see the status though because the terminal went all blank due high cpu usage - probably a bug).

I have come across [similar queries on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711258/import-of-large-dataset-in-neo4j-taking-really-long-12-hours-with-neo4j-impor) with the answers suggesting "So basically, ideally always having separate files for each type of node and rel will give fastest results (at least in my tests)" which is exactly how my data is structured. This is also different from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083529/neo4j-import-tool-hanging), as nodes imported successfully and I have also validated my file for quotation marks - which is the answer to that question. The headers for each file are as follows:

*nodes_chunk.csv (30 GB)*

```
id:ID(chunk),:LABEL
```

*nodes_term.csv (15 GB)*

```
id:ID(term),:LABEL
```

*nodes_article.csv (5 GB)*

```
id:ID(article),title,filename,:LABEL
```

*nodes_assoc.csv (11 GB)*

```
id:ID(assoc),:LABEL
```

*edges_IN_CHUNK.csv (15 GB)*

```
:START_ID(assoc),:END_ID(chunk)
```

*edges_IN_ARTICLE.csv (2 GB)*

```
:START_ID(chunk),:END_ID(article)
```

*edges_IN_ASSOC.csv (2 GB)*

```
 :START_ID(term),:END_ID(assoc)
```

**UPDATE:**

I have removed duplicates from each file to make sure this is not a limiting step, but the issue still persists. Resources are now no longer limiting as CPU and memory usage are below 30% (in contrast to before where CPU was used 100%), and disk is not used. Progress bar shows no improvements at all, so import is not progressing at all.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
I have updated neo4j to 3.4 as the release notes state bulk import has been further optimized for faster import but problem persists. For the above 1/4 node files it takes hours to move by 1% after 50% is reached

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The solution lies on the duplicated_nodes. I preprocessed them to remove any duplication and it worked just fine. I hope this is useful